# Make tcsh wait until specific background job ends + alert me

Tags: wait, tcsh

What "nonblocking" command makes tcsh wait until a specific background
task completes and then "alerts" me by running a command of my choosing?

I want "wait %3 && xmessage job completed &" to wait until background
job [3] is finished and then xmessage me "job completed", but want
this command itself to return immediately, not "block" the terminal.

Obviously, my syntax above doesn't work. What does?

I've written a Perl program that can do this, but surely tcsh can do
it natively?

Comment: Read [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) and reconsider the last phrase in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do something like (untested):

```
while (! $?)
    kill -s 0 $!
    sleep 1
end
```

Or take a look at the `notify` command. I'm not sure if it would do what you want.

Comment: 'notify' is pretty cool, and, if I didn't use 'screen', would be the perfect solution. Unfortunately, I'm not always on the tty where tcsh would notify me (although using screen's monitor-window command...). Your other suggestion is a mini tcsh script that exits when hitting $? with the do-nothing kill signal 0 fails?

Comment: @barrycarter: Yes. You may be able to use that in the background to monitor your other background job.

Comment: OK, I think I'll stick w/ my Perl script, though it's nice to know there's a tcsh alternative.